# How to disable button until radio button is clicked in Vuejs

Tags: javascript, vue.js

```html
<div id="radioButtonsLogin" class="radioButtonsLogin">
  <label for="radio-selection-range-rows" class="radio-custom-label">
   <input class="radio-custom input-group-field" id="radio-selection-range-rows" name="radio-selection" 
   type="radio" checked="checked"><span class="space-radio">Email</span></label><br>

  <label for="radio-selection-range-rel" class="radio-custom-label">
      <input class="radio-custom input-group-field" id="radio-selection-range-rel" 
      name="radio-selection" type="radio"><span  class="space-radio">Phone number</span></label>
</div>
<button :disabled="!radio-selection-range-rows || !radio-selection-range-rel" class="btn btn-danger btn-md mt-40 btn-prime">
              PROCEED
            </button>
```

How to disable button until radio button is clicked in Vuejs. I have two radio buttons followed by proceed btn. So i want to disable button when user doesn't click on radio button, If clicked i want button to move further.

Answer (score 1):

Bind to a common v-model all your radio button so that you can have their value inside the component.

Then, bind the button `disabled` attribute to it, checking if it's empty or not.

```html
<div id="radioButtonsLogin" class="radioButtonsLogin">
  <label for="radio-email">Email</label>
  <input v-model="contactMode" name="radio-email" type="radio">

  <br>

  <label for="radio-phone">Phone number</label>
  <input v-model="contactMode" name="radio-phone" type="radio">
</div>

<button :disabled="!contactMode">
   PROCEED
</button>
```

Note: `<input>` can be outside the `<label>`, it looks cleaner.

Note 2: You should use a `<form>` element to wrap your form

Note 3: You can use  inside your `form` to automatically bind key "Enter" to submit the form, instead of using a manual `<button>`